# How to call a method from another class using connect in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I m trying to create a simple GUI application with the below structure

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.init_ui()

def init_ui(self):
    self.table_widget = MainTabWindow()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)
    self.show()



class MainTabWindow(QTabWidget):

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    #super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    super(MainTabWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.init_ui()

def init_ui(self):
    self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Tab Example')

    self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    #self.selected_date = QDate.currentDate()
    #self.tabs = QTabWidget()
    self.tab1 = QWidget()
    self.tab2 = QWidget()
    self.tab3 = QWidget()
    self.tab4 = QWidget()
    #self.buttonLayout = QMainWindow()

    self.addTab(self.tab1,"Search")
    self.addTab(self.tab2,"Add/Update")
    self.addTab(self.tab3,"Billing Summary")
    self.addTab(self.tab4,"Search2")

    self.SearchTab()
    self.PGCreationTab()
    self.BillingSummaryTab()

def PGCreationTab(self):
  layout = QFormLayout()
  policy = QSizePolicy()
  layout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QFormLayout.FieldGrowthPolicy(2))
  PG_obj = PGDetails()
  fn = PG_obj.setFirstName()
  layout.addRow("FirstName",fn)
  fn.textChanged.connect(PG_obj.getText)

def main():
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainTabWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PGDetails Class -

```
class PGDetails():

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    self.obj = 5
    #self.FirstName = QLineEdit()
    #self.FirstName.setValidator(QIntValidator())

def setFirstName(self):
    self.FirstName = QLineEdit()
    #print("Inside")
    #print(self.FirstName.text())
    return self.FirstName

def getText(self):
    print("Inside")
    print(self.FirstName.text())
```

I m unable to check for any text changes in the First name line box , the function getText never gets called.

If i use self , it throws an error as getText is not defined in MainTabWindow

How can I call the function getText from inside the MainTabWindow class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable that is created from a function only exists until the function ends unless its scope is greater, in your case `PG_obj` is a local variable that will be deleted when the `PGCreationTab` function ends. The solution is to make `PG_obj` have a greater scope for example make it a member of the `MainTabWindow` class.

```
...
self.PG_obj = PGDetails()
fn = self.PG_obj.setFirstName()
layout.addRow("FirstName",fn)
fn.textChanged.connect(self.PG_obj.getText)
```